# Problems syncing document library containing aspx pages

Tags: onedrive-for-business, aspx, sync

I have a document library in Sharepoint Online with mostly pdfs and links to webpages (aspx pages created within Sharepoint via the New 'Link to Document' button). For the users who have *library* permissions set to Contribute, when they try to sync to their local drive using OneDrive for Business, all the pdfs sync fine but the aspx files all have errors, citing that they don't have the needed permissions. However, if they were to add or delete those aspx files in the document library via their browser, they have no problems. From what I've read, the Contribute permissions should be sufficient for aspx files.

Meanwhile, for the users who have *site* permissions set to Design and above, everything syncs fine.

What setting am I missing here for the library Contribute users? It seems excessive to give site permissions to 'Add and Customize pages' just to be able to sync a document library.

Answer (score 0):

Web pages are special in SharePoint. When you upload them, they can either rest in a library as a file or be rendered as a web page. The [Designer permissions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848) allow users to add and customize pages, apply themes and borders, and apply style sheets. When granted the site allows those users to upload web pages.

One of the risks of allowing web pages to be uploaded into SharePoint (a web based platform that may execute uploaded html pages and their script) is that a user may insert a malicious script. To mitigate risk, only designers are allowed to upload files that can possible contain and execute JavaScript. You can read more about the [scripting features here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1F2C515F-5D7E-448A-9FD7-835DA935584F?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Note that when scripts is disabled:

> The following file types can no longer be uploaded to a library
>
> - .asmx
> - .ascx
> - .aspx
> - .htc
> - .jar
> - .master
> - .swf
> - .xap
> - .xsf
>
> Existing files in the library are not impacted.

You may wish to recreate the links using the New button on the OneDrive for Business site. This will create a .url link that can be safely synced.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing I don't understand is that with only Contribute permissions, they ARE able to add these .aspx pages to the Document Library via Sharepoint Online. 

But my question is moot anyway, because I didn't realize these files are useless when not opened in this environment anyway. Thanks, though!